# 'Tag' template parameter in boost::pool_allocator and boost::fast_pool_allocator to support controlling the instance of the underlying pool?

Tags: c++, boost, pool, allocator

**UPDATE**: The question is no longer applicable as I first wrote it, so I have modified the title of the question.  **The question should now be taken to ask** whether modifying `pool_allocator` or `boost_pool_allocator` to accept a `Tag` parameter controlling the choice of underlying pool used (as described in the question) is a good idea - or whether this can be achieved without modifying the library - and if this would be useful for Boost.Pool as an important enhancement if there's no other way to do it.

---

For a project, I depend heavily on Boost.Pool (due to the fact that standard memory deallocation was taking a very, very long time (~30 minutes) for millions of small objects that were never going to be used again).

(See [How to prevent destructors from being called on objects managed by boost::fast_pool_allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942255/how-to-prevent-destructors-from-being-called-on-objects-managed-by-boostfast-p) and [How do you determine the size of the nodes created by a 'std::map' for use with 'boost::pool_allocator' (in a cross-platform way)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951378/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-the-nodes-created-by-a-stdmap-for-use-with?lq=1) for two other questions I posted at the time I was programming this project, related to Boost Pool.)

My scenario is this: **I have many different pools, often storing the same sized objects, that need to be freed at very different times**.  In order to accomplish this, I took advantage of the `Tag` template parameter in `boost::fast_pool_allocator` in order to control pools (specifically, when to delete which pool).

For example, my code has (among many other uses of Boost Pool with different tags) this line - **notice the custom allocator near the end** (a `boost::fast_pool_allocator`):

```
typedef boost::multiprecision::number<
  boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_backend<
    0,
    0,
    boost::multiprecision::signed_magnitude,
    boost::multiprecision::unchecked,
    boost::fast_pool_allocator<
      boost::multiprecision::limb_type,
      boost::default_user_allocator_malloc_free,
      newgene_cpp_int_tag,
      boost::details::pool::null_mutex
    >
  >
> newgene_cpp_int;
```

... with the custom tag defined previously as

```
// Here is the 'tag' type used in the above line of code
// ... this distinguishes the pool used
struct newgene_cpp_int_tag 
{};
```

After much effort and defining at least 20 different pool types, my memory problems were solved, and I moved on.

That was Boost.Pool version 1.55.

I was taken aback to see that in Boost.Pool version 1.56, the `Tag` parameter to `pool_allocator` and `fast_pool_allocator` has been removed.

Here are the two versions:

Version 1.55:

```
// boost::pool_allocator, version 1.55
template <typename T,
    typename UserAllocator,
    typename Tag,  // <-- This was removed in version 1.56: How to distinguish pools?
    typename Mutex,
    unsigned NextSize,
    unsigned MaxSize >
class pool_allocator {...}
```

Version 1.56:

```
// boost::pool_allocator, version 1.56
template <typename T,
    typename UserAllocator,
    typename Mutex,
    unsigned NextSize,
    unsigned MaxSize >
class pool_allocator {...}
```

As you can see, the `Tag` parameter, which makes it possible to distinguish the underlying pool that is used to store objects, has been removed in Boost version 1.56.

Unfortunately, there are no release notes for Boost.Pool (version 1.56) - that is, looking [at the release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_56_0.html) reveals no mention of any changes in Boost.Pool.  Also, a 10 minute Google search revealed no links whatsoever that seemed to discuss the issue.

What should I make of this?  Of course, I could write my own pool allocator class (but if I did this, I'd almost certainly just stick with Boost's version 1.55 - and I would rather not take the time and energy to write my own custom allocator, given that Boost's version 1.55 `pool_allocator` worked just fine).

In particular, I'd like to know - has Boost.Pool dropped support for **controlling pools independently so that they can be freed at different times without worrying about whether the objects are the same size or not between pools**?  If so, I will have no choice but to stick with Boost version 1.55, instead of being able to upgrade.  What a bummer.

Or, is there another way to control the pool used with `pool_allocator` (other than the `Tag` template parameter)?

I would like to know whether I can continue to use Boost Pool's `pool_allocator` as a custom allocator that can control which pools are used, in version 1.56 (and if so, how to do so, given that the `Tag` template parameter has been removed in version 1.56) - and I would also like to know why the `Tag` template parameter was removed in version 1.56, especially if it prevents the ability of using this allocator to control pools.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, [the Boost 1.55 `pool_allocator`/`fast_pool_allocator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp) also have no `Tag` template parameter. Are you sure you are not looking at some sort of custom modification?

Comment: @T.C. You are right!  My God, I forgot that I had modified the class just for this purpose.  Tomorrow, I will update this question to indicate this, and also to perhaps ask if this is the type of modification to the class that might be desired - I certainly needed it!  Apologies to all who took time on this.

Comment: I have updated the title of the question, and added an update at the beginning of the question, to indicate this.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: It might be better to just close this question, since it was never valid, and then suggest your modification on the Boost mailing list or bug tracker (or maybe even here as a new question).

Comment: @JohnZwinck I considered closing it, but thought that perhaps others might run into the inability to control the pool while using `pool_allocator` or `fast_pool_allocator` and might run into this question - where it's clear that it's a simple task to modify the lightweight `pool_alloc.hpp` file to pass through the desired tag, in order to enable this functionality - and that I'm not crazy in wondering. :)  So I figured I would leave it open, and just change the title and add an update at the top of the question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have further modified the title, and "Update" section, to clarify the new purpose of the question.

Comment: Yep, just wondered whether there was a way to give a custom tag to pool_allocator. This answers it. And I'm on Boost 1.67...

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the Tag template argument was transparently "forwarded" to the underlying pool.

The tag type still exists, but isn't part of the public interface. E.g. [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp):

> `const pointer ret = static_cast<pointer>(`
>     `singleton_pool<`**`pool_allocator_tag`**`, sizeof(T), UserAllocator, Mutex,`
>     `NextSize, MaxSize>::ordered_malloc(n) );`

So instead of hard-coding `pool_allocator_tag` and `fast_pool_allocator_tag` you could (again :)) modify the code to pass your own tag to the underlying pool.

---

I suggest you keep your changes as a patch so it's easier to keep up with upstream changes. You could just make a branch of the library at git@github.com:boostorg/pool.git so you can `git rebase` your changes.

Comment: Never thought of cloning the Boost repositories (even though I've never made a change to them before).  Good idea, I'll do that!